# Как рендерить данные из MongoDB с разных useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

У меня есть форма, в которую я записываю три поля (title, content, lead). Записывается всё в одну структуру в ДБ

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
const [content, setContent] = useState('')
const [lead, setLead] = useState('')
```

Всё это записывается в базу данных. Я знаю, что чтобы итерировать данные из базы данных используется подобный синтаксис:

```
return posts.map((post, index) => ({post.title} {post.body}))
```

Вопрос состоит в том, каким образом мне выводить данные из базы, если у меня сразу 3 useState?

Comment: Например? Можно примерный синтаксис? Я в этом деле новичок.

Comment: `const [form, setForm] = useState({ title: '', content: '', lead: '' })`; но я что-то вопрос не понял

Comment: Да, спасибо, то, что нужно